# html - javascript codes merging

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to merge two html/css - js codes together but it doesn't work.

The first html code is a simple button text changed on click:

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

function myTest(btnID)
{
document.getElementById(btnID).value="After";
}

</script>

</head>
<body>

<input type="button" name="toggleBtn" id="toggleBtn" onclick="myTest('toggleBtn')"   value="Before" >
```

And the JavaScript code I want to merge with:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
redirectTime = "5000";
redirectURL = "http://cpanel.hostinger.ae";
function timedRedirect() {
setTimeout("location.href = redirectURL;",redirectTime);
}
//   -->
</script>

<div style="background-color:green;padding:5px;width:110px;cursor:pointer;"
onclick="JavaScript:timedRedirect()">
By M.A JS Code
</div>
```

How can I make the button on click change the text, and then redirect the page by timer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

function myTest(btnID)
{
   document.getElementById(btnID).value="After";

   redirectTime = 5000;
   redirectURL = "http://cpanel.hostinger.ae";
   (function(redirectTime, redirectURL) {
      setTimeout("location.href = redirectURL;",redirectTime);
   })(redirectTime, redirectURL);
}

</script>

</head>
<body>

<input type="button" name="toggleBtn" id="toggleBtn" onclick="myTest('toggleBtn')"   value="Before" >
```

Comment: In your code `timedRedirect()` would never be executed. I doubt, that this is, what OP wanted.

Comment: Yes I just realized that, he simply asked for a code merge and it is what I did, however I fixed that issue (moved the code out of the function as it felt unnecessary)

Comment: This wont work either. The `setTimeout()` callback will be executed in global scope, where the `redirectURL` variable is not known. Better use an anonymous function here.

Comment: It works in jsFiddle but if you do JSHint it will complain about that line as its not best practice. Implied evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

Add the additional code to function you already have: [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/haxtbh/Nes68/)

```
<html>
    <head>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            function myTest(e) {
                e.value = "After";
                redirectTime = "5000";
                redirectURL = "http://cpanel.hostinger.ae";
                setTimeout(function(){location.href = redirectURL;}, redirectTime);
            }

        </script>

        </head>
        <body>

            <input type="button" name="toggleBtn" id="toggleBtn" onclick="myTest(this);" value="Before">

        </body>
</html>
```